# parse check if its undefined/null

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

i've created a filter class which is used for filtering data in another class, but in order to check if the filter should be used i only need to query this data if its not equal to undefined/null. The problem is i keep getting following error?

```
Cannot do a query that requires ordering for type: NSNull'
```

i have following code to check if the keys has a value or not.

The following keys is a number: max and min

the following keys is a array: type, period and room

```
if ([filter objectForKey:@"min"] && [filter objectForKey:@"min"] > 0) {
    [query whereKey:@"type" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[filter objectForKey:@"min"]];
}
if ([filter objectForKey:@"max"] && [filter objectForKey:@"max"] > 0) {
    [query whereKey:@"type" lessThanOrEqualTo:[filter objectForKey:@"max"]];
}
if (![filter objectForKey:@"type"] > 0) {
    [query whereKey:@"type" containedIn:[filter objectForKey:@"type"]];
}
if (![filter objectForKey:@"period"] > 0) {
    [query whereKey:@"period" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[filter objectForKey:@"period"]];
}
if (![filter objectForKey:@"room"] > 0) {
    [query whereKey:@"room" containedIn:[filter objectForKey:@"room"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you have to do is:

```
[query whereKey:@"{key}" notEqualTo:NSNull.null];
```

Swift version:

```
query?.whereKey("someKey", equalTo: NSNull())
```